# Sink upgrade - single sink double wide...any cons?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

We are changing our sink to a single sink. Are there any cons with this configuration?
There will only be one drain and it goes through the garbage disposal.

Comment: Double Or single is a personal preference. The advantage would be 1 less drain connection (less chance for a leak).

Answer (score 2):

Having done this same thing myself a couple years ago, I think the only real downside is not having a built-in divider. And, for me, it's not really that much of a downside. Some people like the divider, since it helps with dishes (you have a wash side and a rinse side), or helps organize dirty dishes. I like having the extra space, and the double-wide single-basin sink allows me to wash bigger pots and pans more easily.

With a single basin, if the drain clogs you're out of luck until you fix it. Or if the disposal leaks. At least with two basins, you could use the other basin until you fix it, assuming the clog isn't past the junction of the two. Unless you clog drains often, though, this is really a non-issue.

Comment: Great feedback! From a purely functional perspective, we are leaning towards the single drain sink (drain is not in the center but closer to the right side of the sink) because we can put many more pots (and bigger pots) in there and not have the divider in the way. Having the drain to the right also means that you can wash and not be concerned that the thing your washing is blocking the drain.